# How to use `gnome-terminal` to open a new terminal window and have a command execute in it?

Tags: bash, command-line-interface, sh

Trying to run a `bash` script to open a new terminal window that runs a simple `ls` command in it.

I've tried different permutations of...

```sh
gnome-terminal --window -e ls
gnome-terminal --window -- ls
gnome-terminal --window [-e, ls]
gnome-terminal -- -e ls
gnome-terminal [-e, --command=ls]
gnome-terminal -- ls
```

I've tried so many more combinations.  I've gone over the `man` and `--help` files and can't seem to understand how to use the `-e` option correctly.  I've read many of the posts here on SO.  The post that is linked as an answer does NOT have usable information that I could use to make the `ls` command run in a new `terminal` window.

When executing the `./file` I would like my bash script to use the `gnome-terminal` command to open a new `terminal` window and run the `ls` command in it.

But while attempting to use the `-e option` I get this error:

```
# Option “-e” is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use “-- ” to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.
```

or sometimes a new `terminal` will open with an error message that says...

```
There was an error creating the child process for this terminal 
...Failed to execute child process “ls” (No such file or directory)
```

I believe the information on `Stack Overflow` about this subject is outdated, as all the posts I could find are years old and offer answers that generate errors for me.  Please help.

Comment: How is this question already answered?  There is no information on how to make gnome-terminal open a new window and run a command in it.  the link offered as the answer to my question does not have any answers.  I still have no idea how to make gnome-terminal open a new window and run a basic command in it.

Comment: _" believe the information on Stack Overflow about this subject is outdated,"_ possibly, but your question itself is off-topic as it is not a programming question.

Comment: What topic should I have submitted this under?

Comment: Possibly on https://unix.stackexchange.com/ or https://superuser.com/